# Acentuação em Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, cmd, acentuação

Estou iniciando em dart e ao usar o stdin.readLineSync() percebi que ele não gravava acentuação. Já tentei mudar o padrão do vscode para utf8 do prompt comando com o comando "chcp" e não funcionou. Alguém tem ideia do que poderia ser? Uso windows 10 64.

```
import 'dart:io';
void main(){
  String? texto = stdin.readLineSync();
  print('$texto');
}
```

Exemplo de entrada: teste áâãóôõ

Saída: teste

Answer (score -3):

Se você está usando o método `stdin.readLineSync()` em seu código e está tendo problemas com caracteres acentuados não sendo gravados corretamente, é provável que o problema esteja relacionado à codificação de caracteres do seu input.

Para corrigir este problema, você pode tentar definir a propriedade `stdin.encoding` como utf8 antes de ler o input do usuário. Isso garantirá que o input seja codificado corretamente em UTF-8, o que pode suportar caracteres acentuados e outros caracteres especiais.

Aqui está um exemplo de como você pode modificar seu código para definir a propriedade `stdin.encoding`:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main(){
  // Set the stdin encoding to utf8
  stdin.encoding = utf8;

  // Read input from the user
  String? texto = stdin.readLineSync();
  print('$texto');
}
```

Neste código, a propriedade `stdin.encoding` é definida como utf8 antes do input ser lido do usuário. Isso deve garantir que o input seja codificado corretamente e que caracteres acentuados sejam gravados corretamente.

Comment: Obtive os seguintes erros: `Desktop/teste.dart:5:20: Error: Undefined name 'utf8'.
  stdin.encoding = utf8;
                   ^^^^
Desktop/teste.dart:5:9: Error: The setter 'encoding' isn't defined for the class 'Stdin'.
 - 'Stdin' is from 'dart:io'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named 'encoding'.
  stdin.encoding = utf8;
        ^^^^^^^^`

Comment: Obtive o mesmo erro ao tentar essa solução.